# Jenkins + Gerrit - How to reject commits with improperly formatted code

Tags: intellij-idea, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit, code-formatting

I would like to my Jenkins to check the formatting of code in comitted files (or in the whole project).

If the format does not conform to the standard (based on IntelliJ code formatting settings), the commit should be rated as Code Review: -2.

Is it possible?
If so, what Jenkins plugins could I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Git::Hooks::CheckFile](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Git-Hooks/lib/Git/Hooks/CheckFile.pm) module of the [Git::Hooks](https://metacpan.org/release/Git-Hooks) framework to achieve this. With Git::Hooks you don't need to use Jenkins and Gerrit Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a gerrit trigger in a jenkins job. The jenkins job would compare the pushed file and the formatted pair of the file. more info how to [format](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/81757815) so if there is a diff between them gerrit trigger will give -2.